# Best practice to update after every n request to python flask?

Tags: python, flask, reinforcement-learning

While building multi-armed bandit method (Thompson Sampling), in production since parameters should get updated after n rewards has been received I want to implement in Flask restAPI.

after every 100 request I get I want to use all rewards I've received then update my parameters in this case alpha and beta.

```
batch_size = 100
ts = ThompsonSampling(batch_size, frames)

@app.route("/route1", methods=["GET"])
def run_ts():
    """When slot opens return frame to be displayed"""

    theta_samples = [np.random.beta(ts.alphas[k], ts.betas[k]) \
                     for k in range(ts.n_actions)]
    a_idx = np.argmax(theta_samples)
    display = ts.actions[a_idx]

    return jsonify({"best_ad":display.name,
                    "expected_ctr":display.ctr,
                    "status":"00",
                    "message":"success"})
```

Every 100 calls to above "route1" I want to update using rewards' I've got (I will be storing it a list then pass it on)

```
def run(self, rewards, a_idx):
    for reward in rewards:
        self.update(a_idx, reward)
```

What is best practice of doing this, and also how should I save rewards? holding rewards and action indexes in a list then sending it back to the API doesn't seem to efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a counter in a database or file. Then increase it everytime you get an request, read the value and if its 100 reset it and run your function.

Comment: why not just add counter inside api upon loading?

Comment: @haneulkim I think you dont understand Interprocess comunication as well as u dont understand the rest pattern. The basic idea is that an server is stateless. If you want to share a global variable i think you neet to dive deep into flasks processing/threading logic. What could work would be using flask application [context](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-contexts/), but in my oppinoin it would be a great idea to keep an rest interface as stateless as possible and store such information in persistent  structures like db or filesystem.